My MERN Web App Converted as Desktop App Using Tauri The Backend Of My App it Not working in Desktop Version
I have created, a MERN Stack Web App and I have converted it into Desktop App Using Tauri (Basically Cargo Tauri ), Everything Is Working Perfectly, Just The Backend Of My App it is working great in web version but Not working in Desktop version.
I Have Tried, Many Things sometimes it works for a bit but as i close and re open the app it is back to not working part,
I Need Help to make it work in Desktop Version as well as in web version of my app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
